# Which Polar heart rate monitors can upload data to Microsoft HealthVault, and how is that upload accomplished?

Tags: upload

The HealthVault site says it supports IR uploading of data, but the Polar website only talks about some "FlowLink" interface of theirs.  Are these the same thing?

If so, what exactly needs to be installed and configured in order to accomplish the data upload to HealthVault?  The Polar web site only talks about uploading to their proprietary web site, and the HealthVault site is light on details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is an IR watch and you're looking to store the fitness data to your HealthVault account, please download the drivers from the HealthVault site and install on a 32-bit PC.  You need an IR adapter to connect to PC and upload using HealthVault Connection Center [ http://www.healthvault.com/personal/devices-overview.aspx ]

If your watch works with FlowLink, you need the FlowLink adapter to connect to PC and upload the data.  HealthVault drivers for Flowlink devices are still in progress and will be available public very soon.

As I understand, both these types of devices works with Polar websync software - but the data is not sync'd to HealthVault.

Hope this helps.